# JavaScript file cannot find a variable

Tags: jquery

I am getting an error at `hasAttr.js` saying that it cannot find the variable :`jQuery`.

Please help me.

I am new to working on the client side.

Comment: I guess you are new at Stackoverflow as well..

Comment: Please check if you have given the proper path to locate the file. And remember when ever you use any thrid party jQuery plugin always locate your jQuery library before the plugin file.

Comment: Can you provide an example page or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

My guess without any other code is that you are not including the jquery library

Answer (score 0):

use google CDN Jquery Libray , use this in your head element

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript>
```